# Is there cleaner syntax for WHERE id != 1 AND id != 2 AND id != 7

Tags: mysql

Is there a cleaner way to perform this query in MySQL?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id != 1 AND id != 2 AND id != 7
```

like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id != (1,2,7)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,7)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  SQL is one of those things I don't use very often , I really ought to spend a day with a book and I'm sure I'll be blown away!